# Logout redirects to default page

Tags: php, wp-redirect, logout

New to wordpress and not a php developer, but I'm currently having an issue with a user being redirected to a default wordpress page and being asked to confirm if the user wants to log out twice. I have added screen shots of what is going on. I tried modifying the function in functions.php that handles the logout and another function wp-login.php (picture below) but have had no luck. Has anyone else ran into this issue before or any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Below are 2 images pertaining to the behavior of my website in its current state. After I click 'logout' in my nav bar, I get taken to the page in the 3rd image below and after i click the logout button, I get taken to a duplicate page and it looks like it tags stuff on the end of the urls query parameters.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url , where you can define where you want to be redirected after a logout.

Comment: Where should this function go? in functions.php or wp-login.php? both files have stuff regarding logging out in them. Im new to WP so im trying to learn best practices

Comment: Functions that are called because of 'hooks' should go in functions.php. You probably want to create a Child Theme, so that changes to that file are not overwritten with a theme update. Lots of tutorials/info on Child Themes on the googles.